# Saving an Outlook Message using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to attach an Outlook message to a Word document entirely using VBA.  I have been able to attach an Outlook Message to another Outlook Message.  I am having problems attaching the Outlook Message to a Word Doc.  I tried saving the Outlook Message to the drive using:

```
message.SaveAs "C:/temp/file.msg", olMSG
```

But it won't save the file.

I also tried recording a macro to see how Word would attach the file, but Word does not record macros for drag and drop from the Outlook Drafts Folder.

Comment: Why is it / and not \ ?

Answer (score 0):

The Word object model doesn't provide any property or method for attaching files.

> But it won't save the file.

Could you please be more specific? Do you get any exception in the code?

Anyway, I'd recommend choosing another folder/drive for saving messages. The C: drive requires admin privileges on latest OS.